# Google App Engine Python - sort by density in ListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is that possible to return a db result which sort by density matching in ListProperty

For example, I have a `db.ListProperty(basestring)` with below value:

```
list_A = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5']
list_B = ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5']
list_C = ['a1','a2','b1','b2','b3']
```

giving `to_be_match_list = ['a1','b1','b2']` and return result in order of density match

list_C return 1st, matching a1, b1 and b2

list_B return 2nd, matching b1 and b2

list_A return last, matching a1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that in BigTable (GQL).

If you grabbed all of the results, however, and wanted to sort them, you could do something like this:

```
some_lists = [list_A, list_B, list_C]
some_lists.sort(key=lambda x: len(set(to_be_match_list) & set(x)), reverse=True)
```